# issue with MenuInflater in the adapter function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-adapter

I am working on my java code to call a function when I click on the RelativeLayout.

When I click on a RelativeLayout, I am calling toggleSelection function to insert the index in the array list and delete the index in the array list.

Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.iconContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            toggleSelection(holder, pos);
        }
    });

    public void toggleSelection(ViewHolder holder, int pos) {
        currentSelectedIndex = pos;

        if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pos);
            animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
        } else {
            selectedItems.put(pos, true);
            animationItemsIndex.put(pos, true);
        }
        Log.e("getSelectedItem...." + getSelectedItemCount, " ");


        if (selectedItems.size() == 1) {
            if (mInboxes.get(pos).getRead().equals("read")) {
                Log.e("passed...5", " ");
            }


            if (holder.action_archive == null) {
                Log.e("passed...6", " ");
                //holder.action_archive.setVisible(true);
            }

            if (holder.action_delete == null) {
                //holder.action_delete.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }
}
```

I want to set the menu items to visible when I click on RelativeLayout, but when I tried this:

```
MenuItem action_read = menu.findItem(R.id.action_mark_read);

if (action_read.isVisible() == true) {
    ...
}
```

It give me an error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference.

Here is the full code:

```
public class InboxAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InboxAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public static List<inbox> mInboxes;
    private Context mContext;
    public String mailbox = "inbox";
    public Window window;
    public InboxAdapter adapter;
    public Fragment _fragment;
    public Menu menu;
    
     public InboxAdapter(Context mContext, List<inbox> inboxes, Fragment fragment) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        _fragment = fragment;
        mInboxes = inboxes;
        selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.iconContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                toggleSelection(holder, pos);
            }
        });


        @SuppressLint({"LongLogTag", "ResourceType"})
    public void toggleSelection(ViewHolder holder, int pos) {
        currentSelectedIndex = pos;

        if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pos);
            animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
        } else {
            selectedItems.put(pos, true);
            animationItemsIndex.put(pos, true);
        }
        Log.e("getSelectedItem...." + getSelectedItemCount, " ");
        MenuItem action_read = menu.findItem(R.id.action_mark_read);
        MenuItem action_unread = menu.findItem(R.id.action_mark_unread);


        if (selectedItems.size() == 1) {
            if (mInboxes.get(pos).getRead().equals("read")) {
                if (action_read.isVisible() == true) {
                    Log.e("passed...5", " ");
                }
            }


            if (holder.action_archive == null) {
                if (action_unread.isVisible() == true) {
                    Log.e("passed...6", " ");
                }
            }

            if (holder.action_delete == null) {
                Log.e("passed...7", " ");
                //holder.action_delete.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can set the menu items to visible in the adapter function??

Comment: `public Menu menu;` is null because you never assign it, but it's not clear where that `Menu` should be coming from.

Comment: @MikeM the menu is coming from the Mainactivity2.

Comment: Well, if you mean it's that `Activity`'s options menu, that's not generally something that should be handled directly in the `Adapter`. However, if you really want to, then you'll need to somehow pass the `Menu` created in your `Activity`'s `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to the `Adapter`; e.g., by adding a `public void setMenu(Menu menu)` method to `InboxAdapter`, and calling that from `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: Yes I mean the `Activity`;s options menu. Can you please show me an example how I can use it to pass the menu in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to the `Adapter`?

Comment: It would be simply adding `public void setMenu(Menu menu) { this.menu = menu; }` to `InboxAdapter`, and then calling `yourInboxAdapter.setMenu(menu);` in `Mainactivity2`'s `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { … }` override. I'm not sure why `InboxAdapter` has a `Fragment` field, but if you're actually using this `Adapter` in a `Fragment`, you could do the same thing in its `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, too.

Comment: Yes I do have fragment but the problem is i am unable to call fragment function from adapter, You might know how I can use `toggleSelection` to call `setMenu` in the fragment from the adapter. Do you know how?

Comment: The problem is with `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) ` it will call `setMenu` only once. I want to keep calling `setMenu` everytime I click on the RelativeLayout. Do you know how I can get the menu from the `MainActivity2` and pass it on to `setMenu` in the `toggleSelection` function?

Comment: Like I mean in the adapter, I use `toggleSelection` function and I put `setMenu` in the fragment so I cant get the `setMenu` function from the fragment. You might know how?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `setMenu()` does. It's just passing the `Activity`'s menu instance to the `Adapter`. You only ever need to do that the one time, when `onCreateOptionsMenu()` runs. The modifications are completely separate. Those you could do in `toggleSelection()`; e.g., `MenuItem action_read = menu.findItem(…);`, `action_read.setVisible(false);`.

Comment: Thanks MikeM, I am using `public void setMenu(Menu menu) { this.menu = menu;` in the Adapter and I use `mAdapter.setMenu(menu)` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and it works great. I can now get access to the `Activity`'s menu with no problem.